# Scrapy: Scrapy.Request does not call recursively

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

My code does not call its function when I try to call it recursively.
I have added comment "#Code does not goes further from here." in the below code so you know from where it does not go further to call another request.
URL [LINK](https://www.hifiklubben.no/api/v2/content/tv-surround/tv//facetsearch/?host=www.hifiklubben.no)

```
import scrapy
import json
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
url_end = '&offset={}'
i = 0

class HKSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
    name = 'HK'
    allowed_domains = ['HK']
    #setting the location of the output csv file
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI' : 'HK.csv'}


    def start_requests(self):        
        yield scrapy.Request(url= url,cb_kwargs={ 
             "pg":"AB","cur":"EUR"}, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response, pg, cur):
        global i
        i = i + 50
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        itemcount = data['resultCount']
        for item in data['filteredItems']:
            item = {
            'Description' : item['availableColors'][0]['productCode'],
            'ProductInformation' : item['modelType'],
            'ProductGroup' : pg,
            'Price': item['priceDetails']['price'],
            'Currency': cur,
            'DataURL': response.urljoin(item['url']),
            'Date': d1,
             }
             yield item    

    #Code does not goes further from here.
        if i < int(itemcount):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.request.url + 
url_end.format(i),cb_kwargs={"pg":"AB","cur":"EUR"}, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy
import json
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
url_end = '&offset={}'
i = 0

class HKSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
    name = 'HK'
    allowed_domains = ['HK']
    #setting the location of the output csv file
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI' : 'HK.csv'}


    def start_requests(self):        
        yield scrapy.Request(url= url,cb_kwargs={ 
             "pg":"AB","cur":"EUR"}, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response, pg, cur):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        itemcount = data['resultCount']
        for item in data['filteredItems']:
            item = {
            'Description' : item['availableColors'][0]['productCode'],
            'ProductInformation' : item['modelType'],
            'ProductGroup' : pg,
            'Price': item['priceDetails']['price'],
            'Currency': cur,
            'DataURL': response.urljoin(item['url']),
            'Date': d1,
             }
             yield item    

    #Moving i from up to here helps to solve problem. :-)
        global i
        i = i + 50
        if i < int(itemcount):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.request.url + 
url_end.format(i),cb_kwargs={"pg":"AB","cur":"EUR"}, callback=self.parse)
```